# Access 2010 VBA Select Case Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, select-case

I am trying to build a function where based on a string comparison use a specific formula

The problem I have is that I get a *Byref arguement type mismatch* error

It must be something to do with passing the string for the comparison and also the numbers for the formulas. Could someone please take a look and help?

```
Public Function MyRateCalc(rateType As String, fixedAmount As Long, minAmount As Long, rateDollar As Long, valPerc As Long, rtValue As Long) As Double

    Select Case rateType

        Case "A1"

            MyRateCalc = fixedAmount * valPerc

        Case "A"

            MyRateCalc = rtValue * rateDollar * valPerc

        Case "B", "C", "D", "H", "L", "N", "R"

            MyRateCalc = IIf(rtValue * rateDollar > minAmount, rtValue * rateDollar * valPerc, minAmount * valPerc)

        Case "M", "U", "MS"

            MyRateCalc = rtValue * rateDollar * valPerc

        Case Else

            MyRateCalc = 0

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for calling the function? You are probably using arguments of type `single` or `double` when they are defined as `long`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function itself is fine.

However the problem will be in the way you are *calling* the function.

In VBA, function arguments are passed by reference (`ByRef`) by default. This means that the data types in the caller have to be exactly the same as those in the function.

Two choices:

1) Adjust your function to

```
Public Function MyRateCalc(ByVal rateType As String, ByVal fixedAmount As Long, ByVal minAmount As Long, ByVal rateDollar As Long, ByVal valPerc As Long, ByVal rtValue As Long) As Double
```

2) Check the caller variable types carefully; they must match exactly.

I prefer approach (1) as it increases program stability (functions cannot unintentionally modify variables in the calling code); even though it's at the expense of a string copy in your case.